# Is is possible to force Pytest to execute class fixtures before module?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am using Pytest, I have a scenario where fixtureA must be called and assign something before fixtureB. and like class A, there are more classes B,C,D and so on with different data types, **so some_data.type is not constant !**

something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def fixtureB(some_data):
  # this needs to happen after A.before()
  some_data.some_calc_after_A()

class A:
  @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
  def fixtureA(some_data):
    # this needs to happen before fixtureB
    some_data.type = 'Fixture_B_needs_this'

  @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
  def setup(fixtureA, fixtureB):
    # this needs to happen after fixtureB

  def test_some_data(setup,some_data):
    # this needs to happen before fixtureB
```

I know pytest follow scope hierarchy, and therefore my class fixture would not be initiated before the module.
But bear with me just for the idea, I was keen for something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def fixtureB(FixtureA, some_data):
  some_data.some_calc_after_A()

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def fixtureA(type:str, some_data):
  some_data.type = type
  yield some_data

class A:

  @pytest.fixture(scope='class')
  def setup(fixtureA(type= 'Fixture_B_needs_this'), fixtureB):
    # this needs to happen after fixtureB

  def test_some_data(setup,some_data):
    # this needs to happen before fixtureB
```

Now I know Pytest does not support this syntax - so I've ended up doing something which I am not very prod of, I've changed the scope of fixtureA inside the class to be a "module" fixture... forcing pytest to call it before fixtureB, because now fixtureA is "module" fixture **but inside a class..**

Well it works, but I am worried that my anti-pattern code will result in side effects and more importantly this is surely not the right thing to do in term of code style & code smell.

Any suggestions how to approach this kind of issue in the best way?

Comment: Your module fixture isn't fixed; you seem to be trying to shove a family of similar class fixtures into one, instead of having a parameterized "fixture generator".

Comment: @chepner My module fixture doing always the same action, but with different param that dynamically generated from a class fixture. how can it be solved with "fixture generator" ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a scenario where fixtureA must be called and assign something before fixtureB

Why not just call the code of the class fixture in the module fixture? I'm deducing that your real problem is that you only want this class fixture executed only when the test for this class will be executed.

From my own experience with PyTest and looking at the documentation there are no pythonic ways to do this apart from hacks or accessing which test are going to be run; and in my opinion this is by design.

The point of having a fixture scoped at the module level is that it is called once for the whole module. If that's not the case then there are no benefit from the tests being in the same module and you should create a different one for each class you want to test.

Comment: I think module fixture does not have access to class fixture.